# Varnish 6.1 : retired return(miss) from vcl_hit {}

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I've just upgraded to debian 10 that is shipped with varnish 6.1

I read that return(miss) is now depreciated, and I then had a look at builtin.vcl

```
sub vcl_hit {
    return (deliver);
}
```

Documentation mentions that to return(miss) we now have to do it via return(restart) + req.hash_always_miss.

So here is my question, how does varnish by default deals with grace and keep ?

Do we have to implement grace our self ?

Can we override default behavior ?

If return(deliver) manages grace, then it seems impossible to force to send an object that has reached into keep period without using a trick using a "permanent failing" backend ?

Or am I missing something obvious ?

Answer (score 2):

Varnish Cache implements grace (i.e. delivery of staled objects and background fetches to refresh them) out of the box. The change in recent Varnish versions is the way to control it. Previously it was `vcl_hit`, but that was deprecated (a lot of detail about that change is available at https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/issues/1799). The new approach is based on the `req.grace` variable (it was removed in Varnish 4.0, but now is back).

If both TTL and grace period have been expired (and if the object still is available in the storage because keep is > 0), Varnish Cache will send a conditional If-None-Match / If-Modified-Since HTTP request to the backend side if possible, and use the object still in cache if a the backend delivers a 304 response.

Comment: Thanks for that info... but here we have wordpress as a backend app. (Can I rely on it to take less time to find a 304 than it is to build the pages ?) And I was happy to have bots get stalled content at same time it's refreshing the cache (50k hits/day) and bots like fast responding websites...

Answer (score 0):

If anyone need to migrate to a newer version of varnish and struggle with implementing `Stale-While-Revalidate` or `Stale-If-Error`.

Those functions are available with their premium extensions but one can mimic this behavior by artificially increasing the ttl of 10d.

A simple check comparing `obj.ttl + obj.grace > 10d` can then give accès to 10 days of `Stale-If-Error` / `Stale-While-Revalidate`.

Was not so simple to implement and took me quite some.

So perhaps this work can be useful to some.

https://gitlab.com/cantoute/varnish-vrocks

This library has been tested in production for a few years now and appears to be stable.

The idea was not have to play with varnish .vcl anymore.

So I created a setup allowing to control, activate/deactivate features by passing headers form the front-end reverse proxy (nginx in my case)

```bash
location @backend {

  ## pass request to backend upstream
  proxy_pass http://varnish_upstream;

  # safety
  proxy_set_header Proxy '';

  proxy_redirect http://$host/ $scheme://$server_name/;

  ## Default is HTTP/1, keepalive is only enabled in HTTP/1.1
  proxy_http_version 1.1;

  ## converts header Link: </url2push> to http2/push
  http2_push_preload on;

  port_in_redirect off;

  ## Remove the Connection header if the client sends it,
  ## it could be "close" to close a keepalive connection
  proxy_set_header Connection '';


  ## enable varnish cache. If disabled, varnish becomes a transparent proxy
  proxy_set_header X-VR-Enabled true;

  ## show some debug data in a response header
  # proxy_set_header X-VR-Debug true;

  ## some presets for wordpress
  proxy_set_header X-VR-Rule-Wordpress true;

  ## when object seems cachable forces remove all cookies
  proxy_set_header X-VR-Clear-Cookie-All true;
  ## or only PHPSESSID cookie
  #proxy_set_header X-VR-Clear-Cookie-PHPSESSID true;

  ## based on saints mode, should we retry on backend error
  proxy_set_header X-VR-Retry-If-Error false;
  
  ## stale-if-error has a hard coded time of 10d
  proxy_set_header X-VR-Stale-If-Error true;

  ## serve stale contents to bots max grace time (<10d)
  proxy_set_header X-VR-Stale-If-Bot 1d;

  ## remove s-maxage, stale-while-revalidate, stale-if-error
  ## from cache-control backend response headers
  proxy_set_header X-VR-Clean-Cache-Control false;

  # clients can use to SHIFT + click "reload" in their browser
  # then cache is bypassed allowing a "refreshed cache" of that page.
  # Note: event if backend returned error the cache is usable (it was never deleted / BAN)
  proxy_set_header X-VR-Force-Reload-Allow true;

  ## fallback default grace period
  proxy_set_header X-VR-Default-Grace 600s;

  ## Should we cache things like .css .js .jpg
  # proxy_set_header X-VR-Cache-Static true;

  ## by default we won't cache ajax requests
  # proxy_set_header X-VR-Cache-Ajax true;
}
```

[Full nginx conf exemple](https://gitlab.com/cantoute/varnish-vrocks/-/blob/master/vrocks/example.nginx.conf)